# Is this early bermuda grass or is it poa annua weed?

Tags: lawn, weed-control

I'm new to yard work, had a lot of crab grass last summer and removed it manually.  The bermuda is dead for the winter in Texas. I'm seeing green, I thought it was bermuda but now I'm learning it might be poa annua.  It looks like poa annua but there are no flowers on it.

I see an herbicide called **Image** to kill it but preserve the bermuda.  Any guidance ?

Comment: A photo might help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.